# Does 4.5.1/4.5.2 replace 4.5?

Tags: .net, .net-framework-version

I have created an vNext app and want to deploy it on a Windows 2008 R2 server. For this I must install 4.5.1/4.5.2.

I want to know what issues can this cause?
Does 4.5.1/4.5.2 replace 4.5?
Can the system choose between 4.5.x and 4.5?

Comment: Anyway all versions before .NET 4.5.2 reach end of life on Jan 12, 2016. You only get a few months left to upgrade.

Comment: @LexLi thanks maybe this will force the admin's hand to install 4.5.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It directly overwrites the 4.5 libraries, so yeah, it's a direct replacement. The two can't really coexist together without some hacks.

And since 4.5.1/2 bring breaking changes, you should really do some testing before committing to the change.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what's new in 4.5.1 and 4.5.2 : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn574802.aspx and http://microsoft-news.com/whats-new-in-net-framework-4-5-2/

Here is another article about the issues that may appear in the migration to 4.5.2: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn720543(v=vs.110).aspx

Here are guides how to migrate your system from 4.5.x to 4.5.2:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2014/08/07/moving-to-the-net-framework-4-5-2.aspx

You can setup your project to whatever version you want, but you cannot make your system choose automaticaly.